# Can I grow a pumpkin in a pot on a balcony?

Tags: pumpkins

I've seen a pumpkin plant hanging down from somebody's balcony, bearing fruits and am wondering, how is it possible? I've tried planting a hokkaido pumpkin into a pot and it grew very small and beared a 5cm fruit, while another seed from the same batch planted into the garden grew normal sized fruits.

I'm in Austria if it matters and will be moving into a flat with a large and sunny balcony.

Here's my not-too-successful attempt:
[image: pumpkin in a pot]

Comment: Did you fertilize it at all?

Comment: No, I've just planted it into the soil I took from the garden, curious, if it will grow at all. The garden was fertilized with some bio-fertilizer from some facility, so I don't really know what was in there :D (the garden itself is not mine)

Since the plant will have access to much less soil in the pot than in the garden I'd have to fertilize it, that's what you're saying?